# Creating sheets with names in column B and assigning data to each sheet for particular name

Tags: excel, vba, database

I have a workbook with master sheet in which I have assigned data to group of people, result wanted is, create sheet for each unique name and copy paste data for that individual to its particular sheet.
I wrote a code but issue is, it is creating just one sheet with first name in list and then copying each row into cell A1:H1 again and again. Not moving to A2:H2 and not creating sheets with other names.

[image: Raw Data][Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQqCr.png)

```
Sub CreateSheetsForNames()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SM")
Set rng = ws.Range("B2", ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In rng
    If Len(cell.Value) > 0 And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sht Is Nothing Then
            Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            sht.Name = cell.Value
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":H" & cell.Row).Copy sht.Range("A1")
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the first occurrence of `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))`, `sht` will NOT be `Nothing` even if `Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value)` should fail

so be sure to set `sht` to `Nothing` at each iteration

while `... .Copy sht.Range("A1")` will always be pasting from cell A1 of the target sheet, hence you have to update the target cell like with `sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

So that you could use the following:

```
For Each cell In rng
    If Len(cell.Value) > 0 And Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        Set sht = Nothing ' set sht to Nothing and erase the result of the preceeding loop
        On Error Resume Next
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sht Is Nothing Then
            Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
            sht.Name = cell.Value
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & cell.Row & ":H" & cell.Row).Copy sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'paste starting from column A first empty cell after last not empty one
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: It is working perfect, the only issue is that newly created sheets doesn't have the header. Header should be the same as the master sheet.

Comment: You are welcome. You may then want to mark the answer as the solution. Thank you

Comment: While as to the headers in the newly created sheets, it’s another item which, by this site rules, you can post a new question of. But my suggestion would be to add a simple copy statement in the same code block where you create a new sheer